# How to calculate π

Tags: computer-science, math-history, pi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple numerical methods for calculating the digits of Pi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297/simple-numerical-methods-for-calculating-the-digits-of-pi)

How do people/computers calculate π?

Im sure long ago, someone just took a measurement of the circumference of circles and their radii and came up with 3.  Then as measurements got more accurate 3.14... etc...

But how do modern people, especially computers calculate π to trillions of digits?

If π is an irrational number, then how do we know the calculations are correct?

Comment: You should google [things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Efficient_methods).

Comment: Related: [How do you calculate the decimal expansion of an irrational number?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147296/how-do-you-calculate-the-decimal-expansion-of-an-irrational-number/147422)

Comment: A nice article of Jonathan Borwein ["The Life of Pi: From Archimedes to Eniac and Beyond"](http://carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/pi-2010.pdf)

Answer (score 11):

Archimedes considered a 96-sided regular polygon inscribed in a circle and another circumscribed about the circle, and found their perimeters, and thereby showed that $3+\dfrac{10}{71} < \pi < 3+ \dfrac 1 7$.

More recently (the past two or three centuries) algorithms derived from the power series for the arctangent function have been used.

In Wikipedia's List of topics related to $\pi$ I find these:

- [Chronology of computation of π](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_computation_of_%CF%80)
- [Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula)
- [Borwein's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein%27s_algorithm)
- [Gauss–Legendre algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm)
- [Proof that 22/7 exceeds π](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80)
- [Leibniz formula for π](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_pi)
- [Liu Hui's π algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liu_Hui%27s_%CF%80_algorithm)
- [Approximations of π](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80)

Wikipedia's  [List of topics related to pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_topics_related_to_pi) --- actually a list of Wikipedia articles on those topics --- is quite interesting:

- 2π theorem
- Approximations of π
- Arithmetic-geometric mean
- Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula
- Basel problem
- Borwein's algorithm
- Buffon's needle
- Cadaeic Cadenza
- Chronology of computation of π
- Circle
- Euler's identity
- Feynman point
- Gauss–Legendre algorithm
- Gaussian function
- History of π
- A History of Pi (book)
- Indiana Pi Bill
- Leibniz formula for pi
- Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem (Proof that π is transcendental)
- List of circle topics
- List of formulae involving π
- Liu Hui's π algorithm
- Mathematical constant (sorted by continued fraction representation)
- Method of exhaustion
- Milü
- Pi
- Pi (letter)
- Pi Day
- PiFast
- PiHex
- Pilish
- Pimania (computer game)
- Piphilology
- Proof that π is irrational
- Proof that 22/7 exceeds π
- Proof of Wallis product
- Rabbi Nehemiah
- Radian
- Rhind Mathematical Papyrus
- Salamin–Brent algorithm
- Software for calculating π
- Squaring the circle
- Tau (2π)
- Turn (geometry)
- Viète's formula

Answer (score 2):

If you really want the answer then this paper might be helpful

http://www.pnas.org/content/86/21/8178