# Ways to determine $\pi$

Tags: numerical-methods, pi, constants

I have read that it is possible to determine the value of a single digit, say the 874th of $\pi$. I know that it is a trascentental number, how is that possible?

How many ways are there to determine the value of $\pi$? What is the simplest?

Comment: Google the Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe formula, which calculates the nth binary digit of pi.

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189820/calculating-pi-manually

Comment: And this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297/simple-numerical-methods-for-calculating-the-digits-of-pi

Comment: @HansLundmark: Not really; many answers to the earlier question are about the asker's wrong premise that "there is no way to actually find out the digits of $\pi$".

Comment: Or here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147296/how-do-you-calculate-the-decimal-expansion-of-an-irrational-number

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Well, pick another one then... There are plenty of answers already explaining how to compute pi.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula

Comment: @HansLundmark None of the questions that you link address the key issue here - namely, how do you compute *some particular* digit of $\pi$ without computing all the *previous* digits of $\pi$. There are several questions (like [this one](http://goo.gl/d9XR8r)) obtained by searching the site for [spigot algorithm for pi](http://goo.gl/7aHC75) that do address that issue.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Well, no, because that was already answered by the first comment... But never mind, I'm not going to waste any more time arguing about this.